# Is there way to set default as null for SQL parameter?

Tags: java, sql, junit, hsqldb

I have a code that creates sql parameters using MapSqlParameterSource. Here is my code:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue(EVENT_ID, eventId)
            .addValue(TYPE, type.toString())
            .addValue(ACCOUNT_ID, null)
            .addValue(USER_ID, null);
        if (Type.SPOOFER_USER == type) {
            parameters.addValue(USER_ID, account.getUser().getId());
        }
        else {
            parameters.addValue(ACCOUNT_ID, account.getId());
        }
```

Basically, if account type is spoofer, I have to have user id instead of account id. However, I don't like that I have to set `account_id` and `user_id` to null when I instantiate `parameters`. Is there way to set `account_id` and `user_id` as null so I don't have to write this two lines?:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue(EVENT_ID, eventId)
            .addValue(TYPE, type.toString())
            .addValue(ACCOUNT_ID, null) //////////////////////////THIS ONE
            .addValue(USER_ID, null);   //////////////////////////AND THIS ONE
```

Here is my sql query:

```
INSERT INTO database (id, event_id, type, account_id, user_id)
    VALUES (database.nextval, :event_id, :type, :account_id, :user_id)
```

Update:

Maybe my question was not specific enough. What happens is that when I run

```
jdbcTemplate.update(insertEventExtra, parameters);
```

With the given parameters without making them "NULL", I get this exception in my unit test:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'user_id': No value registered for key 'user_id'
```

I use hsql to test it. my .sql looks like this:

```
...
ID NUMBER(38,0) PRIMARY KEY,
EVENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
TYPE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER(38,0),
GROUP_ID NUMBER(38,0),
USER_ID NUMBER(38,0),
...
```

So my specific question is that my test is giving me exception when I try to run test with parameters without setting them to null.

Comment: Just don't set them during the insert. They default to null.

Comment: May be I am clueless what's happening here , my question is what is the problem if you just remove the two lines while creating the parameters and add it later as you have shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the addValue(ACCOUNT_ID, null) and addValue(USER_ID, null) because your INSERT statement includes the two named parameters `:account_id`, `:user_id`.

The framework attempts to extract the values for the named parameters from the `MapSqlParameterSource` object and when it does not find one of them, it throws the exception. It does this to avoid user errors, because if you didn't intend to provide a value for a parameter, you wouldn't include the parameter in the INSERT statement.

Comment: oh, so it is designed to thrown an error. I guess I don't have much options if I am sticking with `MapSqlParameterSource` then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your columns nullable and default to null in the database schema. Then, if you don't specify a value for a column when inserting, it should default to null

Answer (score 1):

By default all not null columns have default value of NULL unless and until you provide value while inserting or updating the column.